# Load bitmap or draw graphic? Performance Question

Tags: android, performance

Ok, I am going to be drawing a lot of "insects" on the screen. My question is, if I am drawing a spider for example, would it be faster to load a bitmap, matrix it to the correct angle, and draw it on screen (again and again), or draw an ant using the canvas.drawLine, drawCircle, etc? For a direct comparison:

Bitmap: 500 bytes w/ transparency

Drawn: 8 drawLines, 2 drawCircles

I already have a lot going on, so performance here is very important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you benchmarked both methods?

Comment: Nope, I was hoping to save the time of creating the code to figure out how to draw the spider by asking here if drawing lines and circles is faster than bitmaps. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much faster to draw a bitmap. What really matters is how many pixels you are going to draw (i.e. the overdraw, which will impact the maximum fillrate.) Using bitmaps also allows you to create richer graphics without performance penalties.

Comment: I haven't worked on this in a while, but if I remember correctly, everytime you rotate the bitmap, it creates a new graphic (essentially). In other words, it adds more memory. So if I have 70 ants on screen all in different angles, that's a lot of memory.

Comment: Rotating a bitmap does not allocate memory. Unless you makes the copies yourself of course.

Comment: 70 ants on the screen all going different directions means that each graphic has to be rotated individually to its specified point. Doing so with the matrix requires copies, or is there a way around this?