# Android Canvas -- Draw a Rectangle or a Picture of a Rectangle

Tags: android, performance, canvas

If you always have to draw the same rectangle, it is faster to do it with a static bitmap or with canvas.drawRect()?

For this example, the are four layered rectangles.  So a boarder with a fill color, and then a boarder between a middle color and the fill color.

So four paint.setColor() commands and four canvas.drawRect commands or one canvas.drawBitmap().

Comment: If you do time it, time it without the paint.setColor(); you shouldn't be altering your paints in the draw routine, You should have four paints. Using each for each rectangle. Or reusing them if you paint the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend `drawRect()`.

Bitmaps take up a huge chunk of memory, and can lead to `Out Of Memory` Exceptions if not used correctly.

Written by android:

> Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4 bytes), **immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices**.

To prevent headache, and unexpected crashes. Use `drawRect();`

If you are doing these 4 draws on a regular basis for different objects, consider writing a method that does all 4 for you. So you are not causing massive repetition.

For example:

```
public void DrawMyRect(Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
{
   canvas.drawRect(x, y ,x + 15, y + 40, paint);
   // Draw its line etc etc..
 }
```

Alternatively, if you do go for drawing bitmap, as it does have advantages:

[**See this epic Link by Android, on how to properly use Bitmaps**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643151/load-bitmap-or-draw-graphic-performance-question  I'm getting mixed responses. And my images are small enough that I shouldn't have a memory error.  Performance is all I care about now.  There will be six 32x32 images.

Comment: Added to my answer. If your using small images, there shouldn't really be a problem. Neither will have a definate increase in performance. I have an app here that draws hundreds of lines/shapes etc, in less than a second. If you're using small amount of shapes I don't see any performance problem. If you take bitmaps, I recommend following the link anyway, to ensure you do it effectively.

Comment: @NathanTornquist. Not to mention, that a bitmap would be fixed size, so if you are resizing it, it could end up looking worse. DrawRect is clear, crisp and can be easily changed at no loss of appearance, to fit your shape/needs.

Comment: There will be no effects done to the Bitmap.  Everything is drawn directly without scaling.

Comment: @NathanTornquist Then go for either. The scale on which you need it won't result in any performance loss or memory overflow. If you were looking at 300x300 images they would drain your memory. However this is not the case. So there are no real cons of one method. But no real gains, except as you stated less lines of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference is probably negligible. The bitmap will use more memory, the canvas draw calls will use slightly more CPU. You can probably use a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable) if you want to reduce the calls without the overhead of a bitmap.